# Linearity and invertibility of $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A\in L(X)$ then prove that $A^{-1}$ is linear and invertible.

**Proof:** Since $A$ is invertible then $A$ is injective and surjective. We know that $A^{-1}$ defines by $A^{-1}(Ax)=x$.

*Remark:* Also we can prove that $A(A^{-1}x)=x$. Indeed, if $x\in X$ and $A$ is surjective then exists $y\in X$ such that $x=Ay$. Hence $A(A^{-1}x)=A(A^{-1}Ay)=Ay=x$.

$A^{-1}(x+y)=A^{-1}(Ax_0+Ay_0)=A^{-1}A(x_0+y_0)=x_0+y_0=A^{-1}x+A^{-1}y$ and
$A^{-1}(\alpha x)=A^{-1}(\alpha Ax_0)=A^{-1}A(\alpha x_0)=\alpha x_0=\alpha A^{-1}x$. Hence $A^{-1}$ is linear operator.

We have to prove that $A^{-1}$ is invertible, i.e. $A^{-1}$ is injective and surjective.

If $A^{-1}x=A^{-1}y$ then $x=Ax_0$ and $y=Ay_0$ for some $x_0,y_0\in X$. Then $A^{-1}Ax_0=A^{-1}Ay_0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_0=y_0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=y$.

For any $x\in X$ exists $y\in X$ such that $x=A^{-1}y$. For example, we can take $y=Ax$.

Thus, $A^{-1}$ is invertible and $\exists$ $(A^{-1})^{-1}$. We have prove that $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$. Let $A^{-1}=F$ and $F^{-1}=G$.

For any $x\in X$ we have: $Gx=F^{-1}x$ since $F$ is invertible $\Rightarrow$ surjective then $\exists $$y\in X$ such that $x=Fy.$ Hence $$Gx=F^{-1}x=F^{-1}Fy=y=Ax.$$ Thus $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A.$

Please can anyone check my solution? I would be very grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct, assuming you're using sane definitions for invertibility and $L$.

There are efficiency improvements, though. Like you already proved $A^{-1}$ has a left and right inverse at the beginning. So that demonstrates invertibility without any extra work. That is, assuming you've already proved some stuff about function inverses.